# knockout.js, javascript async calls, and page transition delay

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, knockout.js, navigation, single-page-application

I am running into a weird issue where I have 4 loading async calls that populate certain parts of a page.  I am using the hash to perform javascript navigation without loading the page.  Once I enter the page that is doing the async calls and immediately try to navigate out of it, the page waits until all calls are done before the page navigates to the other page.  This should go to the other regardless if the async calls were done yet or not.  I am using knockout.js to populate HTML to contains the redirect javascript and I know it's getting called because I put logging statements to make sure they were being executed.  Thoughts?

```
app.viewModel.members.container().html("<div>" + html + "</div>");
```

Comment: What is not working as expected ?

Comment: The page should navigate without delay, but it wont until the other loading ajax calls are done on the current.

Comment: So I think you reached the maximum of parallel request.

Comment: Have a look at this http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by keeping a track of the async calls and doing a loop through them and aborting them on page navigation.

**Ajax Calls**

```
 config.request = $
            .ajax({..............

  });

if (!def.cancelRequest)
            config.requests.push(config.request);
```

**Abort Function**

```
 app.abortRequests = function() {
        $(config.requests).each(function(index, item) {
            item.abort();
        });

    config.requests = [];
};
```